# "for everywhere we look" vs "everywhere we look"

Tags: grammar, prepositions

The following piece is from [Crash Course US history](https://youtu.be/lUfh2ebjLOg). It is at 6 minute and 40 second.

> **For** everywhere we look, there is work to be done.

I can understand the sentence; what I cannot get is the use of the preposition *for*
in there. Wouldn't the sentence sound grammatically well on its own.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"For" can mean "because", especially in texts written in literary style:

> Yet this abundant issue seemed to me
>   But hope of orphans, and unfathered fruit;
>   **For** summer and his pleasures wait on thee,
>   And, thou away, the very birds are mute.
>   ([Shakespeare](http://www.shakespeares-sonnets.com/sonnet/97))

Hence,

> **Because**, no matter where we look, there is some work to be done.

This sentence justifies a previously made statement. From [the full text of Obama's speech](https://en.wikisource.org/wiki/Barack_Obama%27s_First_Inaugural_Address):

> Starting today, we must pick ourselves up, dust ourselves off, and begin again the work of remaking America. **For** ("because") everywhere we look, there is work to be done.

We must pick ourselves up and [begin with the work](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=G_Fl5B96rx0), **because** there is some work to be done in all directions.